# query and display the data in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

models.py

```
class ReportType(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Types, null=False, default=False)

class Types(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200)
    parent_type_id = models.CharField('Parent Type', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Is Active', default=True)
```

views.py

```
def method(request):
    report_types = ReportType.objects.filter(report=int(report_id)).select_related("type")[:3]
    return{'what_tab': report_types,}
```

template.html

```
{% if leftbar.what_tab.0.type.title%}{{ leftbar.what_tab.0.type.title}}{%endif%}
```

I am storing the integer value in type column in ReportType model.

I am able to display the 1st item alone into template.I don't know how to display all the saved item into template.

Need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what `leftbar` is, but assuming you got all the other stuff right,

```
{% for tab in leftbar.what_tab %}
    {% if tab.type.title %}
        {{ tab.type.title}}
    {% endif %}
    {% ifnotequal forloop.counter leftbar.what_tab %},{% endnotifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

Since `title` is not nullable, `{% if tab.type.title %}` should never be the case.

Comment: karthikr,the code is woking ,is it possible to separate the 1st and 2nd item with comma(,).I simple put a comma after the loop,it is showing the comma after the 3rd item,which is not required.